# Access 2010 Select Query - Prior business day

Tags: date, ms-access, expression, select-query

I have a select query in MS Access 2010 and need it to pull from the prior business day.
The problem I'm having is I need Friday's data when the query runs on Monday mornings, every other day of the week I only need the prior business day.

Below is one of the formulas I tried which is not working (on Mondays).
Can someone suggest another formula/and or tell me what I'm doing wrong?
    `IIf(Day(Now())=2,Date()-3,Date()-1)`

Answer (score 1):

- `Day` returns the day number of the month.
- `Weekday` returns the day number of the week.
  **Edit:** The 2 in the function indicates the first day of the week is Monday.
- `Now()` returns the current date/time.
- `Date()` returns the current date.

So  `IIF(Weekday(Date(),2)=1,Date()-3,Date()-1)` should work.

Comment: Thanks Darren, I'll give it a try.